# Object.assign / undefined object key

Tags: javascript

I've got an object which I'd like to simplify, based on a condition:

```js
// input
const image = {
  transform: {
    mobile: {},
    desktop: {}
  },
  ...
}

// output - say we only want mobile transforms
const image = {
  transform: {},
  ... 
}
```

My current approach uses `Object.assign` to replace the transform key with either it's `mobile` or `desktop` child, removing a layer of complexity, as well as unused data. There are keys other than transform in the original image object that need to persist.

However, `image.transform` seems to be `undefined` during this operation, although all keys are defined when console logging them.

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'desktop')
```

```js
const image = {
  id: "asdasd123213",
  transform: {
    mobile: {
      top: 2,
      left: 1,
      width: 20,
    },
    desktop: {
      top: 20,
      left: 145,
      width: 260,
    }
  }
}

const images = [image, image, image];
const isMobile = true;

const newImages = images.map((image) => {
  const device = image.transform;

  return Object.assign(image, {
    transform: device[isMobile ? "mobile" : "desktop"],
  });
});

console.log(newImages)
```

Comment: `"transform" !== "transforms"`

Comment: I saw that you're using `transforms` (plural) in your `image` definition, but you're trying to get `image.transform` (singular) when trying to use. In this case, trying to use a value that is not defined explains the error message

Comment: My bad, thats a typo on SO, the actual code both reads plural.

Comment: Why `isMobile ? device["mobile"] : device["desktop"]` when you can write `isMobile ? device.mobile : device.desktop` or `device[isMobile ? "mobile" : "desktop"]`.

Comment: Doesn't make a difference as far as I can tell.

Comment: `Images` is an array of objects in this case. Check the code again :)

Comment: When is "during this operation"? The result is what you expect. Post a runnable snippet that demonstrates the issue, otherwise it's "can not reproduce".

Comment: Sure, working on it.

Comment: You don't need `object.assign` since you can return a new object. Please [see this online jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hd0v8wLr/). I'll post that as an answer with some more details if this question gets reopened.

Comment: There are keys other than transform in the original image object that need to persist.

Comment: To 'keep' the other keys, we can spread (`...`) them with the new object like so: `return {...image, transform: image.transform[(isMobile) ? 'mobile' : 'desktop'] };`. Please see this [JsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wrd061up/)